# Conditional Pipeline (Visual Studio Test) Task in Multi-Configuration Azure Devops 2019 Build Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multi-configuration

We have an on-premises, TFVC setup with Azure Devops 2019. I'm building a C++ library and have set-up a multi-configuration build (Debug, Release) which works fine. However, I'd like to run a set of unit tests only when the Release configuration is building.  I've added a "Visual Studio Test" task which unfortunately is running under both configurations and takes way too long under the Debug configuration. Each test is run in isolation.

I'm not seeing any options to conditionally run the task (I can't edit YAML).

Is there a way to run a task in the pipeline only for a certain configuration?

Comment: Are you using "classic pipeline" (ie that you edit from the UX) or the yaml format? Could you clarify what you mean by "I can't edit YAML"?

Comment: Yes, just the "Classic Editor". YAML does not support the TFVC repository: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/234618/enable-yaml-for-tfvc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you must have the permissions to create, edit and delete the pipeline in the project. If you do not have the permissions, you need to contact the project administrators.

Suppose the variable for the configurations is **`Configuration = Debug,Release`**.
To run a task in the pipeline only for a certain configuration:

1. If your pipeline is created using the classic editor, you can do like as the steps shown on the screenshots below.

- Set the **`Configuration`** variable in pipeline
  [image]
- Set the **Multi-configuration** job, and add condition to skip the **Visual Studio Test** task when the **`Configuration`** is **`Debug`**.
  [image]

2. If your pipeline is created using YAML.

- Using **`if`** conditional to skip the **Visual Studio Test** task.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Build
  strategy:
   maxParallel: 2
   matrix:
     DEBUG:
       Configuration: Debug
     RELEASE:
      Configuration: Release
  steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Show current Configuration'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'echo "Configuration = $(Configuration)"'

  . . .

  - ${{ if eq(variables['Configuration'], 'Release') }}:
    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

In this way, when the **`Configuration`** is **`Debug`**, the **Visual Studio Test** task will be skipped and hidden in the job run.
[image]

- Using **`condition`** to skip the **Visual Studio Test** task.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: Build
  strategy:
   maxParallel: 2
   matrix:
     DEBUG:
       Configuration: Debug
     RELEASE:
      Configuration: Release
  steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    displayName: 'Show current Configuration'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'echo "Configuration = $(Configuration)"'

  . . .

  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
    condition: eq(variables['Configuration'], 'Release')
    inputs:
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

In this way, when the **`Configuration`** is **`Debug`**, the **Visual Studio Test** task will be skipped but not hidden in the job run.
[image]